# Explicitly declaring a variable type in Python

Tags: python, pyscripter

I use [pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) for coding, it supports auto-completion. So, when I say:

```
a = []
a.
```

It gives me all the list functions. similarly with strings I do `b=''`.

But for the `file` type, I have to use `file.` and choose the function and write its arguments and then replace `file` with the variable name.

Is there a way to declare a variable type explicitly in Python, so that my IDE can be more useful?

Comment: Writing bad Python code just to please an IDE doesn't sound like such a great idea to me...

Comment: once you've used `a.your_attribute` in your code, pyDev-eclipse will keep showing that attribute after pressing . in list with CTRL + SPACE, with its intelligence !!!

Comment: If you have to make your IDE absolutely useful, you will have to morph python into java .. including specifying the type explicitly.

Comment: I'm currently switching from C#/Java to Python and the dynamic types seem to create a lot more problems than they solve.  They just feel messy and a step backwards.

Comment: Most decent Python IDEs automatically show possible methods on an object when you type *obj.* : Eclipse, spyder, Wing, Canopy...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to declare variable type, C style in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933197/how-to-declare-variable-type-c-style-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in case you want methods callable on a type ...you can always use dir(var) in python console...

Comment: +1 I think that this is the right answer. Learn the methods available on it the hard way and quit your bellyaching.

Comment: @aaronasterling How silly. "Work harder than you have to simply because languages like Python and Javascript make things more difficult than they have to be."

Answer (score 15):

As of Python 3, you can explicitly declare variables by type:

```
x: int = 3
```

or:

```
def f(x: int):
    return x
```

Comment: Will a warning or Exception be raised if I assign a string to it after explicitly declaring as an `int`?

Answer (score 10):

Python has no type declarations.  Python 3 introduces something called [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), which Guido sometimes refers to as "the thing that isn't type declarations," because the most obvious use of it will be to provide type information as a hint.

As others have mentioned, various IDEs do a better or worse job at auto-completing.