# Python Variable Declaration

Tags: python, variable-declaration

I want to clarify how variables are declared in Python.

1. I have seen [variable declaration](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types) as

```
class writer:
     path = ""
```

sometimes, there is no explicit declaration but just initialization using `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
```

I understand the purpose of `__init__`, but is it advisable to declare variable in any other functions?

2. How can I create a variable to hold a custom type?

```
class writer:
    path = "" # string value
    customObj = ??
```

Comment: And, concerning the 2nd question: in Python, variables don't have type: values do. So any variable can hold your custom objects.

Comment: It will help if you stop thinking of names/idendifiers as being _variables_. They are _references_ to objects

Comment: @gnibbler Or names for them...

Comment: @detly, I think names is a bad choice. Things usually have just one name whereas an object may have multiple references

Comment: @gnibbler True. I remember seeing a nifty pictorial explanation, with boxes and labels, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @detly http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I'm inclined to disagree with that statement on account of Henry McCarty alias Henry Antrim alias Kid Antrim alias William H. Bonney a.k.a Billy the Kid. And, Tellus alias Gaia alias Terra alias Mother Earth alias Earth a.k.a Third Rock From the Sun.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy think of math class. Teacher: "let x be three. Let y be three". Student: "no, you can't have two names for the same thing." I think not.

Comment: @JohnClements, but python doesn't work like math. If you want to understand python you need to know that objects with a `__name__` attribute have a "name". Not all objects have a `__name__` attribute, but you can still have references to them. If we start calling a "reference" a "name" we're doing beginners a disservice down the track.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664294

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Okay, first things first.

**There is no such thing as "variable declaration" or "variable initialization" in Python.**

There is simply what we call "assignment", but should probably just call "naming".

Assignment means "this name on the left-hand side now refers to the result of evaluating the right-hand side, regardless of what it referred to before (if anything)".

```
foo = 'bar' # the name 'foo' is now a name for the string 'bar'
foo = 2 * 3 # the name 'foo' stops being a name for the string 'bar',
# and starts being a name for the integer 6, resulting from the multiplication
```

As such, Python's names (a better term than "variables", arguably) don't have associated types; the values do. You can re-apply the same name to anything regardless of its type, but the thing still has behaviour that's dependent upon its type. The name is simply a way to refer to the value (object). This answers your second question: You **don't** create variables to hold a custom type. You don't create variables to hold any particular type. You don't "create" variables at all. You give names to objects.

Second point: Python follows a very simple rule when it comes to classes, that is actually much more consistent than what languages like Java, C++ and C# do: **everything declared inside the `class` block is part of the class**. So, functions (`def`) written here are methods, i.e. part of the class object (not stored on a per-instance basis), just like in Java, C++ and C#; but other names here are **also** part of the class. Again, the names are just names, and they don't have associated types, and **functions are objects too** in Python. Thus:

```
class Example:
    data = 42
    def method(self): pass
```

**Classes are objects too**, in Python.

So now we have created an **object** named `Example`, which represents the class of all things that are `Example`s. This object has two user-supplied **attributes** (In C++, "members"; in C#, "fields or properties or methods"; in Java, "fields or methods"). One of them is named `data`, and it stores the integer value `42`. The other is named `method`, and it stores a function object. (There are several more attributes that Python adds automatically.)

These attributes still aren't really part of the object, though. Fundamentally, an object is just a bundle of more names (the attribute names), until you get down to things that can't be divided up any more. Thus, values can be shared between different instances of a class, or even between objects of different classes, if you deliberately set that up.

Let's create an instance:

```
x = Example()
```

Now we have a separate object named `x`, which is an instance of `Example`. The `data` and `method` are not actually part of the object, but we can still look them up via `x` because of some magic that Python does behind the scenes. When we look up `method`, in particular, we will instead get a "bound method" (when we call it, `x` gets passed automatically as the `self` parameter, which cannot happen if we look up `Example.method` directly).

What happens when we try to use `x.data`?

When we examine it, it's looked up in the object first. If it's not found in the object, Python looks in the class.

However, when we *assign to* `x.data`, Python will create an attribute on the object. It will **not** replace the class' attribute.

This allows us to do **object** initialization. Python will automatically call the class' `__init__` method on new instances when they are created, if present. In this method, we can simply assign to attributes to set initial values for that attribute on each object:

```
class Example:
    name = "Ignored"
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    # rest as before
```

Now we must specify a `name` when we create an `Example`, and each instance has its own `name`. Python will ignore the class attribute `Example.name` whenever we look up the `.name` of an instance, because the instance's attribute will be found first.

One last caveat: **modification (mutation) and assignment are different things!**

In Python, strings are immutable. They cannot be modified. When you do:

```
a = 'hi '
b = a
a += 'mom'
```

You **do not change** the original 'hi ' string. That is impossible in Python. Instead, you create a **new** string `'hi mom'`, and cause `a` to stop being a name for `'hi '`, and start being a name for `'hi mom'` instead. We made `b` a name for `'hi '` as well, and after re-applying the `a` name, `b` is still a name for `'hi '`, because `'hi '` still exists and has not been changed.

But lists can be changed:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a += [4]
```

Now `b` is [1, 2, 3, 4] as well, because we made `b` a name for the same thing that `a` named, and then we changed that thing. We did not create a new list for `a` to name, because Python simply treats `+=` differently for lists.

This matters for objects because if you had a list as a class attribute, and used an instance to modify the list, then the change would be "seen" in all other instances. This is because (a) the data is actually part of the class object, and not any instance object; (b) because you were modifying the list and not doing a simple assignment, you did not create a new instance attribute hiding the class attribute.

Comment: This is why we call them ['identifiers'](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). :-)

Comment: @Karl_Knechtel in your string example in the end, what happens to 'hi' if we never name it as 'b'? Is this a memory leak?

Comment: @heretoinfinity : no; Python uses garbage collection to free unreachable objects

Comment: > There is no such thing as "variable declaration" - I believe this might not be strictly true nowadays, since you can actually do `something: type` in Python without assigning anything to it. The next paragraph after this statement might also need some rewording because of that.

Comment: I guess one would call this "name annotation" (It's called `AnnAssign` in AST), but I'm not sure how is it different from the general programming concept of declaring something.

Comment: "since you can actually do something: type in Python without assigning anything to it." The thing is, it doesn't actually have an effect, except on function parameters (in which case it adds to the `__annotations__` metadata for the function object). Doing `x: int` in global scope doesn't modify the globals dict, and doing inside a function doesn't change the function's compiled code or its metadata (e.g. the function's `.__code__.co_nlocals` isn't increased).

Comment: But sure, I suppose you could still call that a "declaration", it's just completely unnecessary (it only exists for the benefit of third-party tooling).

Comment: So how do you guarantee there are no typos?  If I start with `field = 6` and inadvertently type `feild = 42` at some point, what's going to barf?

Comment: @kbro You don't; those just become two separate variables naming separate values (rather than re-binding the first one). The problem caused by this (if any) depends on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 40):

This might be 6 years late, but in Python 3.5 and above, you can give a hint about a variable type like this:

```
variable_name: type_name
```

or this:

```
variable_name # type: shinyType
```

This hint has no effect in the core Python interpreter, but many tools will use it to aid the programmer in writing correct code.

So in your case(if you have a `CustomObject` class defined), you can do:

```
customObj: CustomObject
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) or [that](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/learn-how-to-use-static-type-checking-in-python-3-6-in-10-minutes-12c86d72677b) for more info.

Comment: That's not a declaration in the traditional sense, though, it's a hint, which static type checkers and IDEs might point out, but will still run and fail.

Comment: @PhilHibbs It doesn't fail, though. What do you mean by "fail"?

Comment: What I mean is if you do `a: int` and then do `a='hello, world!'` it will not fail, so it isn't declaring a to be an int and only ever an int. I should have said "it won't fail", my bad. If you did `a: int`, `a='hello, world!'`, `a=a+1` then that should fail at compilation in a static typed language.

Comment: In short: the line `variable_name: type_name` is **only** used by third-party type checkers. It has **no effect** on how (the reference implementation, at least) Python bytecode-compiles the code, and **no effect** at runtime.

Answer (score 24):

There's no need to declare new variables in Python. If we're talking about variables in functions or modules, no declaration is needed. Just assign a value to a name where you need it: `mymagic = "Magic"`. Variables in Python can hold values of any type, and you can't restrict that.

Your question specifically asks about classes, objects and instance variables though. The idiomatic way to create instance variables is in the `__init__` method and nowhere else — while you *could* create new instance variables in other methods, or even in unrelated code, it's just a bad idea. It'll make your code hard to reason about or to maintain.

So for example:

```
class Thing(object):

    def __init__(self, magic):
        self.magic = magic
```

Easy. Now instances of this class have a `magic` attribute:

```
thingo = Thing("More magic")
# thingo.magic is now "More magic"
```

Creating variables in the namespace of the class itself leads to different behaviour altogether. It is functionally different, and you should only do it if you have a specific reason to. For example:

```
class Thing(object):

    magic = "Magic"

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Now try:

```
thingo = Thing()
Thing.magic = 1
# thingo.magic is now 1
```

Or:

```
class Thing(object):

    magic = ["More", "magic"]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

thing1 = Thing()
thing2 = Thing()
thing1.magic.append("here")
# thing1.magic AND thing2.magic is now ["More", "magic", "here"]
```

This is because the namespace of the class itself is different to the namespace of the objects created from it. I'll leave it to you to research that a bit more.

The take-home message is that idiomatic Python is to (a) initialise object attributes in your `__init__` method, and (b) document the behaviour of your class as needed. You don't need to go to the trouble of full-blown Sphinx-level documentation for everything you ever write, but at least some comments about whatever details you or someone else might need to pick it up.

Answer (score 18):

For scoping purpose, I use:

```
custom_object = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables have scope, so yes it is appropriate to have variables that are specific to your function. You don't always have to be explicit about their definition; usually you can just use them. Only if you want to do something specific to the type of the variable, like append for a list, do you need to define them before you start using them. Typical example of this.

```
list = []
for i in stuff:
  list.append(i)
```

By the way, this is not really a good way to setup the list. It would be better to say:

```
list = [i for i in stuff] # list comprehension
```

...but I digress.

Your other question.
The custom object should be a class itself.

```
class CustomObject(): # always capitalize the class name...this is not syntax, just style.
  pass
customObj = CustomObject()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3, you can explicitly declare variables by type.

For instance, to declare an integer one can do it as follows:

```
x: int = 3
```

or:

```
def f(x: int):
    return x
```

see this question for more detailed info about it:
[Explicitly declaring a variable type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041764/explicitly-declaring-a-variable-type-in-python)

Comment: What does this add over O. Aroesti's answer?

Comment: well....have you tried following the link I included at the end?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way to declare the variable in Python:

syntax :

```
variable_name = value
```

Example :

```
Name = "Rohan Kumar Bhoi"
ABC = 5
x = "Hello World !"
```

To print the value of a variable, simply use the print function and pass the variable name.

Example :

```
print(Name)
```

output :

```
Rohan Kumar Bhoi
```

---

```
Name = "Rohan Kumar Bhoi"
print(Name)

#output : Rohan Kumar Bhoi
```

Visit This Link to get more Information : [computertipstricks.tech](https://www.computertipstricks.tech/2023/01/variables-in-python.html)