# Python class variables

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/python-variable-declaration)

i'm new to python, and i wonder how to put a proper "empty" variables into classes.

For example, in C++, I can put variables like:

```
public class employee{
private:
int ID;
string name;
public:
.....
}
```

In python, how do I setup the name and the id without giving them values?? Is it something like:

```
class employee:
__name__
__id__
...
```

Also, is it possible to set the data type for each variables?

Comment: What is that you want to achieve?

Comment: In your title, you refer to ["Class variables"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable), but it seems you are actually talking about ["Instance Variables"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable). A class variable has only one value that is shared between all instances of the class, whereas an instance variable (which is what you appear to be talking about in your C code, which I believe is actually C++ code) has one value for each instance of the class that you create.

Comment: @ Mark I didnt know that lol...And yes it should be c++. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that you can't really do that, but here's what you can do:

```
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.whatever = None
```

Also, no need to declare datatypes in Python.  That's the whole point of a dynamic language!

Don't write python with a C++ accent.  Write python the way it was designed and you'll be a lot happier.

Comment: Of course Python has datatypes, lots of them. That's the whole point of strongly-typed languages! (Variables don't have types though - only objects do.)

Comment: Well - there are datatypes - it just happens to be the object that is the type, rather than the name of it... - python is strongly typed, just not statically typed :)

Comment: If there are no datatypes, we should really rename the `TypeError` exception ;)

Comment: I stand correctly corrected :) I'll fix

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

> There's no concept of empty variables in python, they must be
>   initialized to something. And there's no concept of data type either.
>   In python variable names are just symbols pointing to an object(Objects have types though).

```
In [37]: x=2      #x refers to an integer

In [38]: x="foo"  #now x refers to a string object
```

The closest thing to empty variable is to use `None` or `Ellipsis`(py 3x only)

```
In [5]: x=None

In [6]: x

In [7]: x=...        # Ellipsis , py 3.x only

In [8]: x
Out[8]: Ellipsis
```

But again `None` and `Ellipsis` are Objects themselves.

Comment: `None` is how we say "empty" in Python (but it is a real object too).

Comment: Another alternative is not to worry about missing attributes, and define `__getattr__` on the class, which would return a default value - but since we don't really know what the OP wants...