# How to return a value from a function?

Tags: python

Yes, I've read tons of examples on this but I still don't get it.

I'm learning Python and I made this script in order to help me understand how to 'return':

```
def random_number():
    random = 0
    random = (random + 5) * 10
    return random

def calc_pay_rise():
    payrise = 5
    random_number()
    payrise = payrise + random
    print payrise

calc_pay_rise()
```

I expect the output of 55.
Instead I get the error: 'global name 'random' is not defined'. I think I defined what random is in the random_number() function though.

Is there a way to pass the value of random to the function calc_pay_rise()?

Comment: `random` is a variable local to `random_number()`. Seems like you’re looking for `payrise = 5 + random_number()`.

Comment: Please don't call a variable `random`. [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) ist the name of a module from the standard library and you (or an other coder) might get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `calc_pay_rise`, you are throwing away the value returned by the `random_number()` call; instead, do `random = random_number()`. What you've misunderstood is how variables work—local variables in one function (e.g. `def random_number`) are not visible in other functions (e.g. `def calc_pay_rise`).

```
def random_number():
    random = 0
    random = (random + 5) * 10
    return random

def calc_pay_rise():
    payrise = 5
    random = random_number() # assign the value to a local variable
    payrise = payrise + random
    print(payrise)

calc_pay_rise()
```

We can simplify this code by directly returning the value instead of assigning it to a variable first, and by using the result of the call directly in an expression instead of assigning it first:

```
def random_number():
    random = 0
    return (random + 5) * 10

def calc_pay_rise():
    payrise = 5
    payrise = payrise + random_number()
    print(payrise)

calc_pay_rise()
```

The key point here is that the function *returns a value, not a variable*. (Of course, the entire example can be simplified to `print(55)`, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: You could further eliminate some dead code by just changing `random_number()` to `return 50`.

Comment: Well, clearly, but you could just inline `random_number` itself, and then `calc_pay_rise`, and then since its return value is not used, eliminate the call, and end up with an empty program.

Comment: @ErikAllik I thought random = 0 is needed as I need to define the variable. It's very demoralizing, as I'm not understanding anything basically... not sure if this is normal.

Comment: @user2071506: but you are initializing it to `0` and then using the variable to create a new value (that uses that `0`) and immediately assign it back to that variable—so what's the point? Why not just initialize the variable to the desired value immediately? Think about it.

Comment: "I thought random = 0 is needed as I need to define the variable." See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
payrise = payrise + random_number()
```

When you call a function that returns a value (a random number in this case), you're supposed to do something with the returned value.

Also notice that the variable `random` that was defined locally inside `random_number()` can not be "seen" from other functions - unless you declare a new variable locally, but it can have any name you want. Another way to say the same would be:

```
random = random_number()   # can be any name, I'm using `random` again
payrise = payrise + random
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to set a variable named "random"

so your calc_pay_rise function should look like:

```
def calc_pay_rise():
    payrise = 5
    random = random_number()
    payrise = payrise + random
    print payrise
```

Answer (score 1):

your variable "random" in def calc_pay_rise() was never assigned. Try:

```
def calc_pay_rise():
    payrise = 5
    random = random_number()
    payrise = payrise + random
    print payrise
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a python programmers, but this looks like a problem of scope. 
You did define the variable "random" but it's scope-- the section of the code where it is visible and usable-- is limited to the function where you define it.  In this case, *inside* the random_number() function.

It is *not* visible inside the calc_pay_rise() function.
What is visible is the *other function*, random_number() itself. 
That is what you need to use in your addition.

That is the basic point of returning values.