# Replace a list from a variable to a different variable in a different function

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I want to replace the elements from list `letters` with the list elements from list `animals` where as `print(letters)` would print

```
["cat","dog","mouse","rabbit","hamster","duck","chicken","goose","hedgehog"]
```

How do I pass the value of the variable `animals` from the function `newlist` to the function `main` and then replace the value of variable in `main`

Code

```
def newlist():
    animals = ["cat","dog","mouse","rabbit","hamster","duck","chicken","goose","hedgehog"]
def main():
    letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    print(letters)
main()
```

Comment: i'm trying to create an accounting program which gets lists and replace it with list elements from another list... i posted this much for simplicity that's all i need anyways, any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: i think it's very clear. i don't know how to rephrase it clearer. it's just replacing the elements on list `letters` with elements on `animals`.

Comment: `letters = list(animals)`

Comment: that would get an error like animals is not defined. it's from a different function.

Comment: Your question is unclear and it does matter what you will be doing with the code. Many people commenting here know how to solve your problem but don't know what the problem is.

Comment: is saying, how to pass the value of the variable animals from the function newlist to main and then replace the value of variable main a clearer way to say it?

Comment: sigh, answering questions with questions.

Comment: maybe you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080943/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-function, hence create a function, set the letters to the result of this function?

Comment: Change `animals = ...` to `return ...` and then do `letters = newlist()` in `main()`.  If you want to change the actual list object, use `letters[:] = newlist()`

Comment: thnx zondo! i was waiting for that answer. i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do note that functions in Python have to be called and they return specific values or `None` if nothing is specified.

From the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

> The `return` statement returns with a value from a function. `return` without an expression argument returns `None`. Falling off the end of a function also returns `None`.

Hence you need to define your function `newlist` as

```
def newlist():
     animals = ["cat","dog","mouse","rabbit","hamster","duck","chicken","goose","hedgehog"]
     return animals       # RETURN THE LIST
```

This will return the list as intended.

To get the list you need to call the function that can be done using `newlist()`. Hence your `main` function will look like

```
def main():
    letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    letters = newlist()   # CALL THE FUNCTION 
    print(letters)
```

Now when you call `main`, you will get the intended output.

---

You do not need to create a separate list with placeholders. You can directly call `newlist` to get your list ready and working. In such a case the `main` function will be reduced to

```
def main():
    letters = newlist()   # newlist returns a list, so call directly 
    print(letters)
```

Comment: thanks! that is what i was looking for. you're the best!