# Python error with functions

Tags: python, function, defined

I'm trying to write a code but there's something wrong.
I'm not able to print the result of a function.
Here is a mini example of what's wrong in my code:

```
import math

def area(r):
    "It will display the area of a circle with radius r"
    A = math.pi*r**2
    print("The answer is:", str(A))
    return A

area(3)

print(str(A)) # This line is not working

# NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please.

Comment: Also, you're not assigning the return value of `area(3)` anywhere. The `return A` statement doesn't automagically create an `A` variable when the function is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a value from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080943/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a variable within a function, it is defined only within that function and does not leak out to the rest of the program. That is why `A` is not accessible outside of the `area` function.

Using `return`, you are able to send values back to the place where the function was called from.

The last two lines should look like:

```
total_area = area(3)

print(str(total_area))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
print "The answer is: " + str(area(3))
```