# declaring and initialising 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am declaring multidimensional array in python

```
Nbrs[23][2] = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], 
               [2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 3], 
               [3, 1], [1, 4], [3, 4], 
               [4, 3], [4, 1], [1, 5], 
               [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5], 
               [5, 4], [5, 3], [5, 2], 
               [5, 1], [1, 6], [5, 6], 
               [6, 5], [6, 1]
           ]
```

It gives me error as:

```
NameError: name 'Nbrs' is not defined
```

I cannot declare 2 dimensional array in python by this way?

Comment: Python does not have declarations. [See also one of my previous top answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/python-variable-declaration/11008311#11008311).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment statement:

```
Nbrs[23][2] = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2
#    ^  ^ you can't index   Nbrs before it created
```

should be:

```
Nbrs = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2
# now after this statement, Nbrs a list of list you can access 
# its elements useng `Nbrs[i][j]`  for i < len(Nbrs) and j < 2
```

I think you confuses because of C, C++ declarations!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the dimensions when defining lists in python. When you type `Nbrs[23][2]` python is trying to find what's at `[23][2]` in `Nbrs` but in this case `Nbrs` doesn't exist because you are trying to define it for the first time here.

Instead do this:

```
Nbrs = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], ....
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right syntax. You don't need to include anything about the variable's type on the left-hand side; in particular, drop the dimensions.

```
Nbrs = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 3], [3, 1], [1, 4], [3, 4], [4, 3], [4, 1], [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5], [5, 4], [5, 3], [5, 2], [5, 1], [1, 6], [5, 6], [6, 5], [6, 1]]
```

What you've written tries to assign to an element of `Nbrs`, which doesn't exist yet.