# importing a class that I have created in Python

Tags: python

I want to import a class that I have defined and use it in a different file (main.py):

this is the class i have defined:

Example.py:

```
class Example:
  m=0
  n=0

def _init_(self,n,m):
    self.n=n
    self.m=m
```

main.py

```
 from Example import *
 p = Example (2,3)
```

both of the files are at at the same directory 
but when I run main.py I am getting an error:

```
"TypeError: object() takes no parameters"
```

where am I wrong ?

Comment: In error message you should have line number - maybe your problem has nothing to do with import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
```

This is the code you want. The `__init__` has double underscores and it must be proper indented.

Also, your class level `m=0, n=0` does not work the way you expect. It is not a default value to the instance.

Comment: don't u need to define n and m ?

Comment: No, the definition at class level is not what you expect (like in Java for example). You don't need to define variables before set a value to them.

Comment: [There is no declaration (what you apparently meant when you said "define") in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/python-variable-declaration/11008311#11008311).

Comment: Yes, Karl. "Declare" is the correct term, not "define". Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `__init__` function is a [magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html), and thus, has **2** underscores before and after the word.

As other have pointed out, you methods must also be properly indented to be *inside* your class.

Comment: And should be indented properly so it's inside the `class`

Comment: Good points. (Unfortunately) I tend to assume indentation is a copy-paste error.