# How do the variables in a `for` statement get defined?

Tags: python, for-loop

I came across code like this:

```
s1 = "mit u rock"
s2 = "i rule mit"
if len(s1) == len(s2):
    for char1 in s1:
        for char2 in s2:
            if char1 == char2:
                print("common letter")
                break
```

I notice there are no previous defines for the variable like `char1` or `char2`, so how does this work? I think it might be some "keyword for a variable" that Python understands. If so, could you tell me what's it called, and what are other common variables like this?

Comment: That's just how `for` loops work.  I'm not aware of any special term for this specific style of name assignment.

Comment: Karl answers this very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008311/2669081).

Comment: Those *are* the definitions for char1 and char2. There's no " in" variables here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What that for loop does is loop over `s1`. For every iteration it assigns an element of iterable container `s1` to variable `char1`.

Therefore, on the first iteration of the loop `for char1 in s1`, `char1` will have the string value `'m'`, on the second iteration string value `'i'`.

Note that even after the loop has finished executing, `char1` will still have a value assigned (the last iteration means it will have value `'k'`).

What your iterating over doesn't have to be a string, it can be any object that defines `__iter__` and `__next__` methods. So some examples are a list `[1,2,3]` or a generator like what is returned by function invokation `range(5)`.

Comment: Your answer is clear and provides me even more knowledge of iterators and generators. Thank you so much!