# learning python,sample file that's correct from a valid instructor.first time to deal with it,append & pop command do not work on my PC

Tags: python, python-3.x

a.append([1, 2])
print(a)

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 a.append([1, 2])
      2 print(a)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: Well what *is* `a` supposed to be?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to show a complete, runnable code snippet that shows your problem. The cause of your error is almost certainly earlier in your code, not in the two lines you showed us. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this to be part of python code!

to get this working try this:

1. declare your variables.
2. now you can append to the variables.
3. This will append (put on the end) an array containing 1,2.

The code:

```
a = []
a.append([1,2])
print(a)
```

The output will be `[[1,2]]` and `print(a[0])` will output: `[1,2]`

Comment: There is no such thing as variable declaration in python.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/python-variable-declaration

Comment: @user845521 actually that's a sample python file which is already made to show me the right steps,but when i run the command on my PC it gives me that error,even from the same sample file itself.
and thanks already for your time and answering..

Comment: @jonrsharpe (a) supposed to be an assigned value was added and giving the command to add to it the following content

Comment: @AM.D could you add all the things you typed in to the console or upload the sample file?

Comment: @user845521 i got it solved finally!
and thanks for all who tried to help me.
that's encouraging to keep learning.

Comment: How did you do it?