# while calling the function, the same function_name and parameter_name in function creates obstruct! Can anyone explain whats happening?

Tags: python, function-call

```py
#In simple form 

def name(name):
    print(name)

name='arjun'

name(name) #In this line, what's happening?

#Error 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You've renamed `name` from a function to a `str`. Call that string something else and it will fix your problem

Comment: You replaced the function `name` with a string, and you can't call a string as if it is a function.

Comment: `name` is no more a function name but a string instead with the value `'arjun'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Variable Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/python-variable-declaration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not separate namespaces for functions and other objects. If you write

```
def name1(name2):
    print(name2)
```

you create an instance of type `function`, then assign that instance to the name `name1`. (A `def` statement is just a very fancy kind of assignment statement.)

Parameter names are local variables, belonging to the scope defined *by* the function, not the scope *in which* the function is defined. That means you can reuse the name, though it isn't recommended as it can be confusing.

```
   belongs to the scope in which the function is defined
      |
      |    +--- belongs to the scope inside the function
      |    |
      v    v
def name(name):
    print(name)
```

However, the following assignment

```
name = 'arjun'
```

*is* in the same scope as the function definition, so this makes `name` refer to a `str` object instead of the `function` object it used to refer to.