# Beginner: Class/Attribute Concept Confusion (Python)

Tags: python, oop

I am new to python and its OOP concepts, I was following below code and got little confused,

```
class Person:
  species = 'Homo sapiens'
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name= name
    self.age = age

p = Person("ABC", 18)

p.species = 'No homo sapien'
print(p.species)
# prints --> No homo sapien
```

I haven't accessed or manipulated the value of **class attribute species** by just doing `p.species` so it should have thrown some error about `species` attribute, but got no error instead it did print.

```
p.__class__.species = 'Not found'
print("ABC is a {}".format(p.__class__.species))
# error --> SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

This statement threw error as expected. So I want clarification regarding first statement. And can we change class attribute value?

Comment: "so it should have thrown some error about `species` attribute" Why? It would never ordinarily do that. For example, when you do `self.name = name` in the `__init__`, it doesn't raise an exception, even though `self.name` doesn't exist yet. "This statement threw error as expected." No; that error has nothing to do with the code you've shown, and can only happen because of a problem on the previous line of code. There is no problem with the assignment you show there, *whether or not* you have an assignment in the `class` body.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/python-variable-declaration/11008311#11008311 help?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `p.species`, you are creating a new *instance* attribute that shadows the class attribute. `Person.species` will still evaluate to `"Homo Sapiens"`.

```
>>> p = Person("ABC", 18)
>>> p.species = "No homo sapiens"
>>> p.species
'No homo sapiens'
>>> Person.species
'Homo sapiens'
```

If you want to change a class attribute, you have to do it via the class.

```
>>> p = Person("ABC", 18)
>>> Person.species = "Canis canis"
>>> p.species
'Canis canis'
```

Because no instance attribute named `species` exists, `p.species` falls back to `Person.species`.