# Unknown way of declaring a variable

Tags: python

Any documentation for this kind of declaration?

```
x: dict() = {}
y: list() = ()
```

also this works just fine:

```
v: list(list((1,2))) = {}
v["str"] = 1
#v returns {'str': 1}
```

What I understand: Starting the reading from the right; Evaluating the expression then returns its value and associate it to the left after evaluating it.

I did try some other combinations, just gave me more questions.

Comment: Would love to share this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008311/17306932.

Comment: That's a type annotation. The python statement is `v = {}`, a new, empty `dict` is created and assigned to `v`. `: dict()` is an "annotation" - a hint about what you expect `v` to contain. It doesn't affect the execution of the code, but some tools (and readers of the code) may find it useful. See also "Jumped The Shark" IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is supposed to annotate the variable [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), but Python itself completely ignores it (except for making sure the syntax is correct and any variables used therein are defined). It will be read by a static type checker, usually run by code editors to help programmers make fewer mistakes while writing code.

`v: list(list((1,2))) = {}` makes no sense, but Python will take it. As far as Python itself is concerned, this is equivalent to `v = {}`, since it ignores type annotations.

`v: dict[str, int] = {}` makes sense, and tells any static type checker that comes looking that `v` will be a `dict` whose keys are strings and whose values are integers. It will allow a code editor to see that `v["str"] = 1` is okay, and to mark `v[1] = "str"` as an error.

Comment: " and any variables used therein are defined" this behavior is actually slated to change -- `from __future__ import annotations`